# Totals block missing from confirmation mail?

Tags: magento-1.9, totals

The totals block below the item table is missing from my confirmation mail. I checked the mail template and the

```
{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}
```

line is in there so that can not be the problem. The totals block is there in print outs so it is working in general, just missing from that mail.

I have no idea where to look and what to do. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check in:

```
app/design/frontend/package/theme/layout/sales.xml
```

eg:

```
http/app/design/frontend/default/modern/layout/sales.xml
```

Find the block:

```
sales_email_order_items
```

Mine is looking like this:

```
<sales_email_order_items>
    <block type="sales/order_email_items" name="items" template="email/order/items.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>default</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_default</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>sales/order_email_items_order_grouped</block><template>email/order/items/order/default.phtml</template></action>
        <block type="sales/order_totals" name="order_totals" template="sales/order/totals.phtml">
            <action method="setLabelProperties"><value>colspan="3" align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <action method="setValueProperties"><value>align="right" style="padding:3px 9px"</value></action>
            <block type="tax/sales_order_tax" name="tax" template="tax/order/tax.phtml">
                <action method="setIsPlaneMode"><value>1</value></action>
            </block>
        </block>
    </block>
</sales_email_order_items>
```

As you see there's the order_total which should pull the info you need.

### **Edit**

If you're not sure of what sales.xml is been loaded then it would be useful to add the `sales.xml` from **base/default** package into you package/theme.

In this way you'll be sure the file used in your theme will have the  sales_email_order_items block in it.

Comment: Thanks but it is there for me, too. Is there a way to figure out which sales.xml is used? It is not iverwritten in my theme so I guess the one in base/default is being used. THat has the totals block though.

Comment: Why don't you just add that block in your theme so you'll be sure you're loading the proper xml. It's just a thought, let me know how it goes.

Comment: What do you mean "add the block to your theme"? Can you explain pls?

Comment: copy the  sales.xml into you theme. In this way you'll be sure the file is used in it has the sales_email_order_items block in it.

Comment: Yeah, that made it work! Very strange.

Comment: @Arnie, I'm happy you found it useful. P.S.-  I'll add the comment in the post would really appreciate if you would accept the answer. Thank you.